# extract substring regex using printf syntax

Tags: python, regex, string, formatting

I'm a big fan of using the `%` (modulo / string formatting operator thingy), for example:

```
>>> fileName = "par1-%d_par2-%.1f_%s.dat" % (par1, par2, suffix)
par1-5_par2-0.1_hello.dat
```

Is there any package/function which allows you to reverse this process to extract the regex patterns from the string?  e.g.

```
>>> magicFunction(fileName, "par1-%d_par2-%.1f_%s.dat")
1, 0.1, 'hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if such a function exists. As a workaround, you can always rely on regular expressions.

This regex will, for example, match `1`, `0.01`, and `hello` in `par1-1_par2-0.01_hello.dat`.

```
 par1-(\d+)_par2-([\d.]+)_(\w+)\.dat
```

See [example](https://regex101.com/r/bD2yJ1/1).

Example code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'par1-(\d+)_par2-([\d.]+)_(\w+)\.dat')
test_str = u"par1-1_par2-0.01_hello.dat"
re.search(p, test_str)
```

Comment: The reason I asked is because I've never mastered regex syntax; which obviously I should just do...   That website is incredible, thanks!

Comment: You are always welcome :) There are a lot of such sites, just regex101.com provides instant code generation in Python, PHP and JavaScript. To learn regex, you'd better visit http://www.regular-expressions.info/, and to test your own ones, https://www.debuggex.com/ is also very good as it visualizes all regex steps.